# Codeblocks lenguaje C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en codeblocks, él cual se trata un parabrisas manual o automático y se activa cuando llueve o no, Cuando lo inicio y entra al menú principal, con las preguntas A.configuracion,B.simulacion y C. salir, oprimo opción A y sigue al sub menú pero no recibe ningún dato y se termina el programa solo, Y si oprimo B funciona bien pero en ese sub menú cuando elijo una de las opciones que están ahí se vuelve a repetir la pregunta, no se si le faltaria fflush o un system cls o que seria lo que tenia que arreglar del programa

```
        int main()
        {

        int z={7,8,9};

        char op1, op2,op3;

        do{ 

        printf("A. Configuración\n");

        printf("B. Simulación\n");
    
        printf("C. Salir\n");
    
        printf("ingrese una opción deseada:\n"); scanf("%c",&op1);

        switch(op1)
        {
        case 'A':
            do{
            printf("S.modo del sensor automático\n");
            printf("N.modo del sensor manual\n");
            printf("R.regresar\n");
            scanf("%c",op2);

               switch(op2){
             case 'S':
                 printf("\t modo automático\n");
                 printf("elija una velocidad\n");
                 printf("7.velocidad baja\n 8.velocidad media\n 9.velocidad alta:\n");
                 scanf("%d",z);
                 printf("el sensor esta en modo automático y con una velocidad de %d\n", z);
                 break;

             case 'N':
                 printf("\n modo manual");
                 printf("elija una velocidad\n");
                 printf("7.velocidad baja\n 8.velocidad media\n 9.velocidad alta:\n ");
                 scanf("%d",z);
                 printf("el sensor esta en modo manual y con una velocidad de %d \n",z);
                 break;
               }

            }while(op2!='R');
            break;

             case 'B':
                do
                {
                  system("cls");
                  printf("S.esta lloviendo\n");
                  printf("N.sin lluvias\n");
                  printf("R.regresar\n");
                  scanf("%c",&op3);
                  switch(op3)
                  {
                  case 'S':
                    printf("esta lloviendo\n el sensor se activa automáticamente\n velocidad: media");
                    break;
                  case 'N':
                    printf("no esta lloviendo\n el sensor esta manual\n-velocidad: alta");
                    break;
                  }

                }while(op3!='R');
          }

    }while(op1!='R');
  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuáles son esas **ciertas partes**? No esperarás que alguien tome tu código y se ponga a buscar algo que no especificas. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para agregar más detalles, trata de ser más específico con algún escenario que sepas que no funcionará y especificas cuál es el problema o el error, porque así tú pregunta queda muy abierta. De paso te sirve para solventar el problema de el mínimo de carácteres. También te recomiendo realizar el [tour] (y te ganas tu primer medalla) y también que leas [ask].

Comment: ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]?

Comment: A simple vista veo que tienes varios `scanf` mal implementados, ya que cuando insertas la variable para almacenar el dato no incluyes la dirección `&`. Intenta poner siempre la estructura `scanf("%c", &variable_char)` para capturar un `char` ó `scanf("%d", &variable_int)` para capturar un `int`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo edite y trate de ser mas especifico con la pregunta

Comment: Ya he solucionado el problema de mi programita, les faltaba; system cls,system pause,getch, y fflush(stdin), gracias por hacerme dar cuenta de los & porque no los habia visto..